# Multi index dataframe delete row with maximum value per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi index dataframe like this:

```
PID    Fid    x      y

  A      1    2      3
         2    6      1
         3    4      6
  B      1    3      5
         2    2      4
         3    5      7
```

I would like to delete the rows with the highest x-value per patient (PID). I need to get a new dataframe with the remaining rows and all columns to continue my analysis on these data, for example the mean of the remaining y-values.
The dataframe should look like this:

```
PID    Fid    x      y

  A      1    2      3
         3    4      6
  B      1    3      5
         2    2      4
```

I used the code from [Python Multiindex Dataframe remove maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669129/python-multiindex-dataframe-remove-maximum)

```
idx = (df.reset_index('Fid')
                   .groupby('PID')['x']
                   .max()
                   .reset_index()
                   .values.tolist())
df_s = df.loc[df.index.difference(idx)]
```

I can get idx, but not remove them from the dataframe. It says TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
idx = df.groupby(level=0)['x'].idxmax()
df[~df.index.isin(idx)]

         x  y
PID Fid      
A   1    2  3
    3    4  6
B   1    3  5
    2    2  4
```

Or

You can use `pd.Index.difference` here.

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(df['x'].groupby(level=0).idxmax())] #Use level=0 if index is unnamed
                                         #('PID').idxmax())] 
         x  y
PID Fid      
A   1    2  3
    3    4  6
B   1    3  5
    2    2  4
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked for me. The first one resulted in the error : KeyError: 'PID'

Comment: @NienkeH Use `groupby(level=0)` in first one too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat max values per groups, compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_s = df[df.groupby('PID')['x'].transform('max').ne(df['x'])]
print (df_s)
         x  y
PID Fid      
A   1    2  3
    3    4  6
B   1    3  5
    2    2  4
```