# Delete rows with conditions (Multi-Index case)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I have this Data Set :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 88, 4: 88, 5: 323, 6: 323},
         'Step': {0: 'A', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'F', 3: 'F', 4: 'Bar', 5: 'F', 6: 'A'},
         'Num': {0: 38, 1: 38, 2: 38, 3: 320, 4: 320, 5: 433, 6: 432},
         'Date': {0: '2018-08-02',
          1: '2018-12-02',
          2: '2019-03-02',
          3: '2017-03-02',
          4: '2018-03-02',
          5: '2020-03-04',
          6: '2020-02-03'},
         'Occurence': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}})
```

*The variables 'ID' and 'Step' are Multi-index*.

I would like to do two things :

FIRST :

If 'Num' is different for the same 'ID', then delete the rows of this ID.

SECONDLY :

For a same ID, the step 'F' should be the last one (with the most recent date). If not, then delete the rows of this ID.

**I have some difficulties because the commands df['Step'] and df['ID'] are NOT WORKING ('ID' and 'Step' are Multi-Index cause of a recent groupby() ).**

I've tried groupby(level=0) that I found on [Multi index dataframe delete row with maximum value per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560546/multi-index-dataframe-delete-row-with-maximum-value-per-group)

But I still have some difficulties.

Could someone please help me?

Expected Output :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4},
         'Step': {0: 'A', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'F'},
         'Num': {0: 38, 1: 38, 2: 38},
         'Date': {0: '2018-08-02',
          1: '2018-12-02',
          2: '2019-03-02',
         'Occurence': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3}})
```

The ID 88 has been removed because the step 'F' was not the last one step (with the most recent date). The ID 323 has been removed because Num 433!=Num 432.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated that ID and Step are in the index, we can do it this way:

```
df1[df1.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')['Num']\
       .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & 
                            (x.index.get_level_values(1)[-1] == 'F'))]
```

Output:

```
         Num        Date  Occurence
ID Step                            
4  A      38  2018-08-02          3
   Bar    38  2018-12-02          3
   F      38  2019-03-02          3
```

#### How?

- First sort the dataframe by 'Date'
- Then group the dataframe by ID
- Taking each group of the dataframe and using the 'Num' column to transform in a boolean series, we
  first get the number of unique elements of 'Num' in that
  group, if that number is equal to 1, then you know that in that group
  all 'Num's are the same and that is True
- Secondly, and we get the inner level of the MultiIndex (level=1) and
  we check the last value using indexing with [-1], if that value is
  equal to 'F' then have a True also

Comment: Wow thank you it works perfectly, and you're keeping the variables in the index. Gj !

Comment: Well I still have a question... Your code is doing perfectly, but I don't get how it works, especially this part : \
       .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & 
                            (x.index.get_level_values(1)[-1] == 'F'))]                      Could you explain me please?

Answer (score 2):

- Group the dataframe by column `ID`
- `Transform` the `Num` column using `nunique` to identify the unique values
- Transform the `Step` column using `last` to check whether the last value per group is `F`
- Combine the boolean masks using *logical and* and filter the rows

```
g = df.groupby('ID')
m = g['Num'].transform('nunique').eq(1) & g['Step'].transform('last').eq('F')
```

```
print(df[m])

   ID Step  Num        Date  Occurence
0   4    A   38  2018-08-02          3
1   4  Bar   38  2018-12-02          3
2   4    F   38  2019-03-02          3
```

---

Alternative approach with `groupby` and `filter` but could be less efficient than the above approach

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: g['Step'].iloc[-1] == 'F' and g['Num'].nunique() == 1)

   ID Step  Num        Date  Occurence
0   4    A   38  2018-08-02          3
1   4  Bar   38  2018-12-02          3
2   4    F   38  2019-03-02          3
```

Note: In case `ID` and `Step` are MultiIndex you have to `reset` the index before using the above proposed solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot ! However I think there is still a mistake : g['Step'].transform('last').eq('F') doesn't work, because it doesn't depend on the position of 'F', but about the date. For example, look at my df in my post. The 2 last rows would be deleted because of g['Num'].transform('nunique').eq(1). But if both num error are the same, with your code, the rows would be deleted because 'F' isn't in the last position. However in this example, 'F' has the most recent date, so it should be not deleted

Comment: Oh i thought it would depend on the position of `F`. But if you want to check last value corresponding to max date we can sort the values beforehand. Please check `g = df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')`

Comment: Yep it works ! Thank you for all your answers ! Scott Boston did a pretty good job too O_o not using reset_index and keep variables in the Multi-Index

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly.
But you can try this

```
import os
import pandas as pd 

sheet = pd.read_excel(io="you_file", sheet_name='sheet_name', na_filter=False, header=0 )

list_objects          = []

for index,row in sheet.iterrows():
    if (row['ID'] != index):
        list_objects.append(row)
```

*list_objects* will be a list of dict

Answer (score 0):

use groupby to find the rows with 1 occurrence.  I drop the rows in the dataframe based on the ID return by the groupby results.   I exclude IDs with one occurrence and not include those in the deletion.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 88, 4: 88, 5: 323, 6: 323},
     'Step': {0: 'A', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'F', 3: 'F', 4: 'Bar', 5: 'F', 6: 'A'},
     'Num': {0: 38, 1: 38, 2: 38, 3: 320, 4: 320, 5: 433, 6: 432},
     'Date': {0: '2018-08-02',
      1: '2018-12-02',
      2: '2019-03-02',
      3: '2017-03-02',
      4: '2018-03-02',
      5: '2020-03-04',
      6: '2020-02-03'},
     'Occurence': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}})
df.set_index(['ID','Step'],inplace=True)
print(df)
print("If 'Num' is different for the same 'ID', then delete the rows of this ID.")

 #exclude id with single occurrences
 grouped=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0)]).size().eq(1)
 labels=set([x for x,y in (grouped[grouped.values==True].index)])

 filter=[x for x in df.index.get_level_values(0) if x not in labels]

 grouped = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(filter)].groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),'Num']).size().eq(1)

 labels=set([x for x,y in (grouped[grouped.values==True].index)])
 if len(labels)>0:
     df = df.drop(labels=labels, axis=0,level=0)    
 print(df)
```

output:

```
  Num        Date  Occurence
  ID Step                            
  4  A      38  2018-08-02          3
     Bar    38  2018-12-02          3
     F      38  2019-03-02          3
  88 F     320  2017-03-02          2
     Bar   320  2018-03-02          2
```